# How to add spaces between nodes when using string() on a tree in XPath

Tags: html, xslt, xpath, lxml

I have a HTML tree where I use the `'string()'` query on the root to get all the text from the nodes.

However, I'd like to add a space between each nodes.

I.e.

`string()` on `'<root><div>abc</div><div>def</div></root>'` *will* become `'abcdef'`

`string()` on `'<root><div>abc</div><div>def</div></root>'` *should* become `'abc def '`

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @TimC I'm using the lxml package in Python. From it's docs: "lxml supports XPath 1.0, XSLT 1.0 and the EXSLT extensions through libxml2 and libxslt in a standards compliant way."

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a short example of the input XML and the expected output. Also clarify why is the string() function required here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I do not know how to make it more clear without repeating myself or using other words to say the same thing. There literally is the input, the current output and the wished output examples. Though I added some `root` node, maybe that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `itertext()` method, that iterates over all text content:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML('<root><div>abc</div><div>def</div></root>')
print(' '.join(e for e in root.itertext()))
```

It yields:

```
abc def
```

Comment: Does make me wonder what the xpath is underneath. Traced it down to some cython, but not sure if it just concatenates text+tails.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what output you want when the XML is more complex than shown, or when it involves mixed content. In XSLT 1.0 you'll have to do a recursive descent of the tree, involving something like

```
<xsl:template match="div">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"> </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

> `'<root><div>abc</div><div>def</div></root>'` should become `'abc def '`

In XSLT 1.0, this would be done as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="div">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or perhaps you meant to retrieve all text nodes, regardless of the document structure. This could be done by:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```